# Перемещение Trail с помощью Rigidbody

Tags: unity3d, разработка-игр

Я создаю платформер с помощью Unity. И я хочу поменять `MoveTrail` скрипт. Я хочу передвигать trail с помощью `rigid body` вместо `transform.translate`.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class MoveTrail : MonoBehaviour {
    public int moveSpeed = 230;
    public Rigidbody2D rb;
    // Update is called once per frame
    void Start(){
        rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D> ();
    }
    void FixedUpdate () {
        Vector3 curPos = new Vector3 (transform.position.x, transform.position.y, transform.position.z);

        transform.Translate(Vector3.right * Time.deltaTime * moveSpeed);
        Destroy (gameObject, 1);
    }
    void OnCollisionEnter2D(Collision2D collision){
        if(collision.gameObject.tag == "Wall"){
            Debug.Log ("Wall");
            //do something ex: sound effect, visual effect etc
            Destroy (gameObject);
        }
    }
}
```

Как я могу сделать это?

Comment: На русском stackoverflow принято задавать вопросы только на русском языке, пожалуйста переведите.

Comment: rb.position+=Vector3.right * Time.deltaTime * moveSpeed;

Comment: @Xumera_hZ Assets/Scripts/MoveTrail.cs(16,6): error CS0121: The call is ambiguous between the following methods or properties: UnityEngine.Vector2.operator +(UnityEngine.Vector2, UnityEngine.Vector2)' and UnityEngine.Vector3.operator +(UnityEngine.Vector3, UnityEngine.Vector3)'

Comment: rb.position+=Vector2.right * Time.deltaTime * moveSpeed

Comment: @Xumera_hZ пули летят только вправо. При этом поворот пули правильный.

Comment: Ну так поменяй вектор направления, Vector2.right на свой вектор, ну можешь на крайняк поставить transform.forward

Comment: @Xumera_hZ Мне надо что бы trail летел в сторону мышки.